imputeLCMD proteomic mising values data
I am working with a DIAnn PASEF proteomics dataframe in R. However, some of the columns contain a lot of missing values (NAs) that I need to impute in order to perform a comprehensive analysis. I have attempted to use the R package imputeLCMD to impute the missing values in my dataframe.
df <- data.frame(protein = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
meanA = c(1.2, NA, 2.3, NA, 3.1),
meanB= c(NA, 2.9, 1.5, NA, 2.6), 
meanC = c(NA, 2.9, 1.5, NA, 2.6), 
meanD= c(1.8, NA, 3.4, 2.2, NA))

df2 <- as.matrix(df[,-1])
rownames(df2) <- df$protein

imputed_matrix <- impute.MAR(df2, 1, method = "MLE")

Next, I have tried to use the impute.MAR function from the imputeLCMD package with the MLE method.However, I have noticed that the function only imputes some of the missing values and not all. I would like to understand why the function is not imputing all the missing values and if there are any different approaches or additional parameters that I should consider to improve the imputation results.

MAR = missing at random. From the docs for that function: This function performs missing values imputation under MAR/MCAR hypothesis.. And the value returned: dataset containing only MNAR (assumed to be left-censored) missing data. If you are imputing in multiple steps, you might then as a next step impute MNAR values, e.g. values missing not at random (e.g., "left-censored" or values below some assumed detection threshold). You might use imputeLCMD::impute.MinProb() to impute those values assumed to be low.

Thank you, however when I evaluate the model according to imputeLCMD::model.Selector(), it returns that most of the rows containing random missing values MAR, not MNAR

I've haven't used impute.MAR() personally (but I've used other functions in the package), but it looks like argument 2 model.selector requires a "binary vector" of 1's and 0's to indicate which rows you would like to impute as MAR/MCAR. Looking at the source code (https://github.com/cran/imputeLCMD) under imputeMAR.R you can see that the model.selector argument is used to subset the matrix for which values to impute. You probably need to adjust the argument there to impute your desired rows.

Might also be worth mentioning: other packages often seem to often use the methods in the imputeLCMD package and expand from there to give more fine-tuned options. For example, in some workflows you might want to impute within a row some experimental arm values as MAR and other values in a different experimental arm with many more missing values as MNAR. For imputeLCMD::impute.MAR() it looks like it will impute the whole row for you. Hope this helps
